# Eclipse: Many Class Files

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, build, jar

I would like to know why I got like 30 ClassFiles in the "bin" folder for my Program.java program.

They are named as followed:

```
Testworks$1.class
Testworks$2.class
Testworks$3.class
Testworks$4.class

...
```

and there is one `Testworks.class`

When I generate my Program.jar file all 30 `Testworks$X.class` are copied inside.

Do I really need them and how can I exclude them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These classes are anonymous inner classes. If you have used GUI programming,you might have noticed them. When you create listeners for events, you might do something like:-

```
Button okBtn = new Button("Ok");
okBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){//this is an anonymous inner class

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
   //your code here
  }
  ...
  ...

});
```

This inner class has no explicit name, hence the compiler names it using the convention OuterClass$x.class. x is replaced by the number of inner class (for eg, 1, 2..etc)

Answer (score 2):

You do need them, they are anonymous classes that you have in your code. The compiler compiles them into this naming scheme (`Outer$x.class`).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the code you've written. If you have something like the below, it will generate these `$` class files.

```
List<Person> persons = ...

Collections.sort(persons, new Comparator<Person>() {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
});
```

If you don't want to see the `$` files for any reason, simply declare the anonymous comparator in a separate class.

```
public class PersonComparator implements Comparator<Person> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person p1, Person p2) {
        return p1.getName().compareTo(p2.getName());
    }
}
```

And use it as: `Collections.sort(persons, new PersonComparator());`

Answer (score 0):

Inner classes gets compiled to that.